# Remix sees my custom network as main net?

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, private-blockchain

Hi I have made custom geth network with custom genesis and chain id, but remix sees my network as main net.
[image]

[image]

Genesis is hard coded to the geth code.

```
func DefaultGenesisBlock() *Genesis {
    return &Genesis{
        Config:     params.AvesMainnetChainConfig,
        Nonce:      0,
        GasLimit:   0x7fffffffffffffff,
        Difficulty: big.NewInt(0),
        // addr 0xd9c9cd5f6779558b6e0ed4e6acf6b1947e7fa1f3
        Alloc: map[common.Address]GenesisAccount{                               // 2 milion AVES / aves 18 digits
            common.HexToAddress("0xB0061ACb424DB252D52a9E97B90824300855885E"): {Balance: new(big.Int).Mul(big.NewInt(20000000), big.NewInt(1e18))},
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you specify a different network id? If you didn't specify it is using the same id as mainnet.